# Generalization of a FFT with powers of 3

Tags: algorithms, fourier-analysis, recursive-algorithms

I'm not satisfied with the current answers asked about this on MathSE. So I'm going to ask:

*Describe the generalization of the FFT algorithm to the case in which n is a power of 3. What's the runtime?*

Comment: What is missing in this [directly related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66890/cooley-tukey-fft-with-arbitrary-radices?rq=1)? And in [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632593/fft-with-powers-of-3?rq=1)?